# How to transform the tree data into one-line-data using rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a problem here:
for example, the tree data:

```
[{
    key: 1,
    value: 1,
    children: [{
        key: 11,
        value: 11: children: []
    }]
},
{
    key: 2,
    value: 2,
    children: []
}]
```

Now I want this:

```
[{key:1,value:1},{key:11,value:11},{key:2,value:2}]
```

How to deal with that using rxjs or something else? Any opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: you can recreate it by checking whether node has children or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a depth first recursive traversal of the tree with something like. This makes assumptions that your input data is consistent.

```js
let arr = [{key: 1,value: 1,children: [{key: 11,value: 11,children: []}]},{key: 2,value: 2,children: []}]

function flatTree(arr){
  return arr.reduce((res, {key, value, children} ) => 
      res.concat({key, value}, ...flatTree(children))
    , [])
}

console.log(flatTree(arr))
```

You can also do this in a single nested `reduce()`:

```js
let arr = [{key: 1,value: 1,children: [{key: 11,value: 11,children: []}]},{key: 2,value: 2,children: []}]

let r = arr.reduce(function flatTree(res, {key, value, children} ) { 
      return res.concat({key, value}, ...children.reduce(flatTree, []))
  }, [])

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a recursive function & loop through the array. While looping check if the current key-value is an array or not. If it is an array then call the recusrive function again with new data

```js
let data = [{
    key: 1,
    value: 1,
    children: [{
      key: 11,
      value: 11,
      children: []
    }]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: 2,
    children: []
  }
]

let finalArray = [];

function formatData(data) {


  data.forEach((item) => {
    let obj = {};
    for (let keys in item) {

      if (Array.isArray(item[keys])) {
        formatData(item[keys])
      } else {
        obj[keys] = item[keys];
      }

    }
    finalArray.push(obj)
  })
}
formatData(data);
console.log(finalArray)
```